# How to use mouse without borders in 2 separate locations

Tags: windows, mouse

I found mouse without borders and it works great. I have my laptop and desktop at home setup and using it daily. I would also like to use mouse without borders at work as well.

I want to use my laptop at work AND at home. Obviously they are not on the same network and I don't need to connect my work pc to my desktop. Is there anyway to setup two completely different sessions on the same computer?

Comment: I know exactly that there is such ability in synergy http://synergy-foss.org